# "We couldn't retrieve the real-time tile history" when using IConfidentialClientApplication WithClientSecret()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, powerbi, azure-ad-msal, powerbi-embedded

I am experimenting with the app owns data (or "embedding for your customers") model for Power BI. I have set up a very basic test workspace with a real-time streaming dataset (with historic data analysis enabled, so it is actually push-streaming) and created a dashboard with a single tile to display the past minute of what that dataset has received. I believed I had been quite thorough in setting up the app in Azure and Power BI, granting it permissions, etc., but I appear to have missed something.

I am using the Microsoft Authentication Library ([Microsoft.Identity.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/)) and Microsoft Power BI API ([Microsoft.PowerBI.Api](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerBI.Api/)) in my ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application and am able to embed this dashboard and see the tile update in real-time if I use the `IPublicClientApplication AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword()` methodology for obtaining my access token:

```
using (SecureString securePassword = new SecureString())
{
    IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create("MY-APPLICATION-ID")
        .WithAuthority(Path.Combine("https://login.microsoftonline.com/", "MY-TENANT-ID"))
        .Build();
    string[] scopesDefault = new[] { Path.Combine("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/", ".default") };
    "MY-PASSWORD".ToList().ForEach(x => securePassword.AppendChar(x));
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await publicClientApplication
        .AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopesDefault, "MY-USERNAME", securePassword).ExecuteAsync();
    string accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

[image: Working tile]

However, if I switch to the `IConfidentialClientApplication WithClientSecret()` methodology for obtaining my access token, which is preferred for security reasons, that same tile errors out like this (and there is no helpful information if I click "See details"):

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create("MY-APPLICATION-ID")
    .WithClientSecret("MY-CLIENT-SECRET")
    .WithAuthority(Path.Combine("https://login.microsoftonline.com/", "MY-TENANT-ID"))
    .Build();
string[] scopesDefault = new[] { Path.Combine("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/", ".default") };
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await confidentialClientApplication
    .AcquireTokenForClient(scopesDefault).ExecuteAsync();
string accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

[image: Errored tile]

Curiously, pinned report visuals for this same real-time dataset show up just fine on this dashboard regardless of the authentication methodology I employ.

**What must I do to get that tile to work with the `IConfidentialClientApplication WithClientSecret()` methodology so I don't have to use a username and password?**

Comment: Is there any useful information under *See details* link on the error page?

Comment: Nope, nothing worth sharing. Just some GUIDs I could send to Microsoft in a support ticket if I'd like to (which I have, but am also exploring this avenue for help simultaneously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with Microsoft on this and after consulting with their product team, they told me that currently, streaming tiles are not supported in Service Principal (which is the technology behind the Client Secret methodology).